# How to remove this error?

Tags: magento-2.0

There has been an error processing your request

Please upgrade your database: Run `"bin/magento setup:upgrade"` from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:

```
Magento_CustomWidget schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0

Magento_CustomWidget data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Error log record number: 1078485663282
```

my code is module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

`<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">


<module name="Magento_CustomWidget" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and it's likely to be caused by renaming your module(ie: when you try to make a backup copy and leave it in the same directory, ideally we should first disable the module then make a copy), and you must have run bin/magento setup:upgrade - not knowing that you're registering two identical module into database.
How I did to fix the issue was to go to database table: `setup_module` and find the entry in your case is: `Magento_CustomWidget`, then update the schema and data both to `2.0.0`. It's an easy fix if you have phpmyadmin, see if it helps.